# WCF Error With WebInvoke BodyStyle Wrapped

Tags: c#, json, wcf, webinvoke

I have a problem when trying to create a method that takes 2 or more parameters. I specified to use Wrapped BodyStyle on the operationcontract but anyways it gives an error like if I wasn't using it.

Interface:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = 
"/DaysDeleteBusinessDay", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
[OperationContract]
void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id);
```

Service:

```
[WebInvoke]
public void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id)
{
    Logic.LogicFabric.GetLogicDays().DeleteBusinessDay(BusinessesId, Id);
}
```

Comment: Error like if I wasn't using it. What is the error?

Comment: Operation '' of contract '' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve the problem, I also added to the definition of the method in the service

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id)
```

And thats all.

Thanks to all!